# evaluating the array of strings using libsvm

Tags: java, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

i'am using java libsvm , i created my model and now i want to evaluate it with the array of string , i've done that for the array of doubles

but i don't know how to evaluate for the array of strings , i hope if there is somebody to help me

thanks in advance,

this code work with the array of doubles

```
private double evaluate(Neighbor features, svm_model model) {
    svm_node[] nodes = new svm_node[features.getDocument().getAttributes().size()];
    Iterator<String> iteraitor = features.getDocument().getAttributes().keySet().iterator();
    int i = 0;
    while (iteraitor.hasNext()) {
        svm_node node = new svm_node();
        node.index = i;
        String key = (String) iteraitor.next();
        node.value = (features.getDocument().getAttributes().get(key));
        nodes[i] = node;
        i++;
    }
int totalClasses = 2;
    int[] labels = new int[totalClasses];
    svm.svm_get_labels(model, labels);

    double[] prob_estimates = new double[totalClasses];
    double v = svm.svm_predict_probability(model, nodes, prob_estimates);

    for (int j = 0; j < totalClasses; j++) {
        System.out.print("(" + labels[j] + ":" + prob_estimates[j] + ")");
    }
    // System.out.println("(Actual:" + features[0] + " Prediction:" + v + ")");

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVM is a geometrical classifier that works in `R^n` space, it accepts **only numerical** values. To use SVM on strings you have to do one of the following:

- transform strings/documents into some feature representation (numerical), like [tfidf](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/TFIDF) etc.
- use a [string-based kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_kernel) (like `wordnet kernel` etc.), which will introduce the numerical feature space by itself

`libsvm` allows of use of precomputed kernel values, so if you implement some kernel `K(x_i,x_j)` you simply have to provide `libsvm` with kernel matrix, where `K[i,j]=K(x_i,x_j)` (where `x_i` is `i'th` training example).